# Can ResizeObserver listen just to width change?

Tags: javascript, next.js, resize-observer

I want to trigger ResizeObserver only on width change and not use it if height was changed. Is it possible?

Example:

```
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(setLayout);
resizeObserver.observe(layout.current);

const setLayout = () => {/*do something*/}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in  function, but you can make a wrapper that checks if (only) the width has changed:

```js
const ro = function($el, cb) {
  let last = $el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const observer = new ResizeObserver(function() {
    const data = $el.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(data.width !== last.width && data.height === last.height)
      cb();
    last = data;
  });
  observer.observe($el);
}
```

Then use it like:

```js
ro(layout.current, setLayout);
```